# disable entry to cell if another cell is not empty

Tags: excel

How do I render any cell in range ("A1:A10") uneditable (cannot be changed) if there is any content in 2 cells to the right (same row, column C), and make that cell editable again once the cell in same row column C becomes empty.
I tried the code below but it has no effect, i can still edit the cells in col A even with content in col C. Ideally I would like to have it done without protecting sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C10")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
      Target.Offset(0, -2).Cells.Locked = True
      ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Thank you,
Jay

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

'*** Note: I need to reside in the Sheet Module for the
'          sheet I am working on!

'*** Note: Make sure the Locked flags for A1:A10 and
'          C1:C10 are cleared before implementing.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim rng As Range

   Application.EnableEvents = False  'Turn off Events to prevent loop!
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C10")) Is Nothing Then
    
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect 'You need to unprotect before proceeding
      
      For Each rng In Target
      
         If rng <> "" Then  'Checking for Target.Address will always have a value!
           rng.Offset(0, -2).Locked = True
         Else
           rng.Offset(0, -2).Locked = False
        End If
      
      Next rng
      
      ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True 'Turn Protection back on
      '*** If you have other protected elements DrawingObjects and/or Scenarios
      '    you need to include in line above.
      
  End If
  
 Application.EnableEvents = True  'Re-enable Events
  
End Sub 'Worksheet_Change
```

HTH

Comment: Hi HTH,  it works but when i'm trying to select multiple cell in column C i'm getting a Run_Time Error "13". I need to be able to select multiple cells so exiting sub when selecting multiple cells is not an option. any other way to overcome this error?

Comment: Why would you be selecting multiple cells. If you're doing data entry you'll work on one at a time in C1:10. What is you're requirement for selecting multiple cells? How would that be processed?

Comment: Hi,  This sheet is an example of our is daily operating menu, so it makes it easier if i'm able to delete all entries when starting new days operating menu. I dont always have the same number of rows filled in.

Comment: Hi HTH,  I'm new to this site and I want to mark this question as answered but dont see how/where. can you direct me
Thank you.

Comment: Jay, there should be a check mark to the left of the answer, just click it. BTW: HTH is "Hope this helps", not my initials. RG

Comment: Oh Boy! please excuse my ignorance... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Jay, I just edited my answer to allow you to clear the C1:C10 as a contigious range. It also works if you just select a group of cells in that range using the Control Key.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `Target.Address` on being an empty string. Why? Shouldn't that be `Target.Value`?

In top of this, what's going wrong? Did you debug the code, using breakpoints? What did you see? ... In case my answer does not satisfy your needs, please edit your question and add the needed information.